# App crashes due to 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKAnnotationView setPinColor:]

Tags: iphone, mkannotation

My code for annotation is:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *identifier = @"RoutePinAnnotation";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[UICRouteAnnotation class]]&&[(UICRouteAnnotation *)annotation annotationType] != UICRouteAnnotationTypeWayPoint) 
    {

        MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if(!pinAnnotation) {
            pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        }

        if ([(UICRouteAnnotation *)annotation annotationType] == UICRouteAnnotationTypeStart) {

            pinAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;


        } else if ([(UICRouteAnnotation *)annotation annotationType] == UICRouteAnnotationTypeEnd) {
            pinAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

        }
        pinAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinAnnotation.enabled = YES;
        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
        return pinAnnotation;
    }





}
```

App runs fine first but when we zoom the map it crashes.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception **NSInvalidArgumentException**, reason: `-[MKAnnotationView setPinColor:]`
Please help me!! Thanks

Comment: Is this all the code in viewForAnnotation?  What about when annotationType is WayPoint?

Comment: does this compile without warnings? it shouldn't...

Comment: I was using same identifier for annotationType start,end and waypoint.  I used  static NSString *identifier = @"RoutePinAnnotation";
for start and end